# How to calculate the distributed of samples come from Gaussian distribution？

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

The question says, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are samples come from a same Guassian distribution $N(0, \sigma^2)$, prove that Statistics $x_1/x_2$ and $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ are independent.

I'm really confused how to calculate the distributed of $x_1/x_2$, can anyone explain this specificly?

Comment: Try [Basu's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem).

Comment: Note that you'll need $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be independent. Alternatively to using Basu's theorem (which is probably what I'd do), look at transforming ($X_1, X_2$) to polar coordinates and showing those new variables are independent, from which the above result can be obtained.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, when I first meet this question, I thought I should find the joint distributed of $x_1/x_2$  and $sqrt(x_1^2 + x_2^2)$, after that, I could find out their distribution respectively and prove that their joint distribution is equal to the multiply of their own distribution. However, I'm not sure how to calculate the distribution of $x_1/x_2$ . And I have browsed the Basu's theorem,  is this means I ought to prove the $x_1/x_2$ is the statistic of the origin distribution at first?

Comment: $X_1/\sqrt{X_2^2}$ is, *by definition,* the Student t distribution with one degree of freedom.  It should be clear that this has the same distribution as $X_1/X_2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered in depth here:

[Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959094/if-x-and-y-are-independent-n0-sigma2-then-x2y2-and-x-y-are-ind)

The idea is writing the joint density and switching to polar coordinates, where it can be seen that the transformation of the random variables (which are the ones you ask about) gives a joint density which can be simply factorized, which implies that the two newfound variables are independent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Wengzhiqiang no problem. If the answer worked for you, you can mark it as solved.